# TCL Destructor is not called on window close

Tags: tcl, destructor, exit

I have a class `DataDialog`, which contains a destructor like

```
destructor {
    puts "DataDialog has been destructed"
    #further code
}
```

If I close the application via the `X`-window-button this destructor is not called. If I close it over `file->close` it is called.

On the toplevel I have the following

```
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW { 
    Exit 0
}
```

How can I change this behaviour to call all destructors (or at least the one of my class DataDialog)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW { 
    DataDialog destroy
    Exit 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `exit` (or if you delete the interpreter) then Tcl *does not guarantee* to call destructors. That's because tearing down everything in memory can be surprisingly expensive. Critical resources typically have extra exit handlers registered at the C level to ensure that they get cleaned up correctly, but they're very much the exception; the only ones you likely use on a common basis are channels (which are flushed on exit). There isn't any Tcl-level for doing this; those handlers are usually called at points where it is no longer safe to call Tcl commands.

However, the default behaviour for handling cooperative window closure is effectively to send a `<Destroy>` message to the window. Those aren't entirely interceptable (the window *will* go away) but you can `bind` to them to find out when they occur. Be aware of one quirk though: toplevel windows also listen to all the events of their children (though they don't get killed by passing `<Destroy>`s unless they're sent to them directly). Check that `%W` actually refers to the window that you think you're really listening to before taking special action.